# How to save a list of dictionary to a .mat file in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of dictionaries. Here is one element of the list:
`mylist[1]` gives following dictionary.

```
{'bitrate': None,
 'channels': None,
 'duration': 107.927,
 'filename': 'CANCION DE POKEMON GO  SONIDO DE INICIO POKEMON GO(SLM)',
 'filesize': 19642323,
 'samplerate': None}
```

I create each dictionary in a for loop very simplified below:

```
mylist=[]
for loop
dict=create the dictionary
mylist.append(dict)
```

I have tried:

```
sio.savemat( "testmat.mat", mylist)
```

but it gave a long error.

How can I save mylist to a .mat file?

Comment: google is your friend my friend --> https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.savemat.html

Answer (score 0):

`scipy` has a simple helper function `scipy.io.savemat` for this.

```
import scipy # scipy is installed

# ... generate mylist

fname = "my_filename" # arbitrary filename

scipy.io.savemat(fname, {"Data": mylist})
```

Note that `savemat` expects a dict so you must reform `mylist` into a dict if only by making a one-key-value-pair dict as shown in the example.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I have decided to use csv dictionary writer instead.